# How to relate keys from two tables in to one foreing key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
create table PreDefinedPkg
(
    PPID varchar(10),
    packageName varchar(100),
    preDefPkgPrice float,
    Primary key(PPID)),
    foreign key (userID) references User(userID)
);

create table CustomPkg
(
    CPID varchar(10),
    custPkgPrice float,
    Primary key(CPID)),
    foreign key (userID) references User(userID)
);
```

I have above two tables and I need to create below table as

```
create table Booking
(
    bookingID varchar(10),
    noOfPassenger int,
    completeStatus varchar(5),
    approveStatus int,
    tripDate date,
    bookedDate date,
    relatedTable varchar(100),
    relatedPkg varchar(100),
    userID varchar(100),
    foreign key (userID) references User(userID),   
    primary key(bookingID)
);
```

How can I obtain the package IDs from PreDefinedPkg and CustomPkg in to the field 'relatedPkg' in booking table as a foreign  key of these two tables in MySQL

Comment: Is your DB Oracle ?

Comment: You can't. Create two fields and a foreign key for each table (on each column). There is no such possibility in any database. Also your table definitions are wrong and will thrown error because of the `;` before of the foreign key definition.

Comment: You could push the validation into triggers (before insert,before update) on booking.BTW  'obtain the package IDs from'  is an odd way to put it - FKs are constraints which validate data by reference to other tables.